# Make android can updated

Tags: android, ios, updates

I will deploy my app to Google Play/App Store, and I will have some new update function in the future, how can I make my app can automatic update when I release a new version, I have to write code or Google Play/App Store handler it for me.

Sorry for asking question b/c I dont know which key word I have to search in Google.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your application, in your manifest file you give it a version number. For example version 1. If you create a second version of your app, you change that number (increment usually) and then re-publish your app on the Play Store. Then the users that already have your app downloaded will get a notification that there is an update for your app.